# Return the median of a column as Long

Tags: apache-spark

I am calculating the median of one column of my dataset.
I can't find a method to get the median as long (all i get is as double)
Here's my attempt :

```
double median_val = Arrays.stream(dF.stat().approxQuantile("col0", percentiles, 0.0)).findFirst().getAsDouble();
```

can't find a `getAsLong()` method,
How to achieve that ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Java 8's (as I'd assume you use at the moment) docs, `Stream`'s [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) returns an `Optional` object which does have a [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#toString--) method, so in a way you can convert the `String` into `long` like this:

```
long median_val = Long.parseLong(Arrays.stream(dF.stat().approxQuantile("col0", percentiles, 0.0)).findFirst().toString());
```

However, this seems way too clunky and not at all straightforward (*if* it works, in some cases), so your best bet is casting the `double` into a `long` object by using one of the following ways:

```
long medianValLong = (long) median_val;               // simple casting
long medianValLongRound = Math.round(median_val);     // rounding off to the nearest long of the double
long medianValLongParse = Long.parseLong(median_val); // same as the first, clanky, way, without involving a String conversion
```

Comment: you've lost a bracket in the last one I think?

Comment: Indeed I did, thank you for notifying me. Updated.